# If $G/H_1\cong H_2$ and $G/H_2\cong H_1$, can we conclude that $G\cong H_1\times H_2$ if $H_1, H_2\neq \{\operatorname{id}_G\}$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Consider a (discrete or continuous) group $G$ and two normal/invariant subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ (possibly invariant/normal subgroups). Provided that $H_1,H_2\neq \{\operatorname{id}_G\}$, if $G/H_1\cong H_2$ and $G/H_2\cong H_1$, can we conclude that $G$ is the direct product of $H_1,H_2$, i.e. $G\cong H_1\times H_2$?

If not, then what can we conclude about the relationship between $G, H_1$ and $H_2$ if $G/H_1\cong H_2$ and $G/H_2\cong H_1$?

Comment: You say "possibly invariant/normal", but group structures on the quotients $G/H_1$ and $G/H_2$ are not defined if they are *not* normal.

Comment: Do you really mean tensor product, or to do you mean direct product?

Comment: @LeeMosher True. I was not careful. Thank you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin direct product. I edited the question to include this. Thank you.

Comment: Well, then why not use the direct product symbol, `\times`, rather than `\otimes`?

Comment: Likely not much; I expect an isomorphism isn't strong enough to guarantee $H_1$ and $H_2$ have nearly anything to do with each other. Even when $G=H\times K$, it is possible for there to exist an automorphism $\alpha$ of $G$ for which $H_1=\alpha(H)$ and $H_2=K$ fulfill the hypotheses and yet $G\ne H_1\times H_2$ even though the isomorphism types of $H_1,H_2,G/H_1,G/H_2$ are the exact same as $H,K,G/H,G/K$ were!

Comment: For instance, take $H=\Bbb Z_2^2\oplus 0$ and $K=0\oplus\Bbb Z_2^2$ within $G=\Bbb Z_2^4$. Then $H\cong K\cong G/H\cong G/K$, but if we apply the automorphism $\alpha$ that swaps the middle two coordinates to $H$ to get $H_1$ and let $H_2=K$, then we still have $H_1\cong H_2\cong G/H_1\cong G/H_2$ but now $H_1\cap H_2$ is nontrivial!

Comment: @runway44 if you're willing on turning these comments into an answer, I'd make it the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good exercise to find counterexamples in small groups, not just for this question but for many basic group theory questions! Try cyclic groups, for example. If $n=ab$ is composite then $G=\Bbb Z_n$ has subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ of orders $a$ and $b$ respectively, then $G/H_1\cong H_2$ and $G/H_2\cong H_1$ since all subgroups and quotient groups of a cyclic group are cyclic (which are unique up to order).

(If you want $H_1\ne H_2$ of course choose $n$ with $a\ne b$.)

Likely we can't tell much at all from $G/H_1\cong H_2$ and $G/H_2\cong H_1$ because mere isomorphism is an equivalence relation with too much "freedom" to move around within. Even if $G=H\times K$ is a direct product, there can be an automorphism $\alpha$ for which $H_1=\alpha(H)$ and $H_2=K$ satisfy the same hypotheses but $G\ne H_1\times H_2$ is not a direct product!

For instance, suppose $H=\{(w,x,0,0)\}$ and $K=\{(0,0,y,z)\}$ within $G=\mathbb{Z}_2^4$ and let $\alpha$ be the automorphism (of $G$) defined by $\alpha(w,x,y,z)=(w,y,x,z)$ (it permutes the middle two coordinates); evidently $G=H\times K$ but defining $H_1=\alpha(H)=\{(w,0,x,0)\}$ and $H_2=K$ we know $G\ne H_1\times H_2$ since there is nontrivial intersection $H_1\cap H_2=\{(0,0,x,0)\}$! Yet $H\cong K\cong G/H\cong G/K$ all have the same isomorphism type as $H_1\cong H_2\cong G/H_1\cong G/H_2$.

Answer (score 2):

For the main statement:

**Hint.** The smallest counter-example has order $4$. The smallest counter-example with $H_1\not\cong H_2$ has order $8$.

The rest of the question needs more focus.

Comment: The smallest counterexample has order $4$.

Comment: @the_fox Whoops! Thanks for pointing that out. For some reason, I was assuming $H_1\not\cong H_2$.